# How Can I add active class using mouse hover in menu item with jquery?

Tags: javascript, css

I used This code but Its only work on click event but I want to set it in hover and click both, hover option just will be for hover and when hover out it will remove that active class.

```js
(function() {
    [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.menu')).forEach(function(menu) {
     var menuItems = menu.querySelectorAll('.menu_link'),
      setCurrent = function(ev) {
       ev.preventDefault();

       var item = ev.target.parentNode; // li
       
       // return if already current
       if( classie.has(item, 'menu_item-current') ) {
        return false;
       }
       // remove current
       classie.remove(menu.querySelector('.menu_item-current'), 'menu_item-current');
       // set current
       classie.add(item, 'menu_item-current');
      };
     
     [].slice.call(menuItems).forEach(function(el) {
      el.addEventListener('click', setCurrent);
     });
    });

    [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.link-copy')).forEach(function(link) {
     link.setAttribute('data-clipboard-text', location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname + '#' + link.parentNode.id);
     new Clipboard(link);
     link.addEventListener('hover', function() {
      classie.add(link, 'link-copy--animate');
      setTimeout(function() {
       classie.remove(link, 'link-copy--animate');
      }, 300);
     });
    });
   })(window);
      


( function( window ) {

'use strict';


function classReg( className ) {
  return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
}

var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

if ( 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return elem.classList.contains( c );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.add( c );
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.remove( c );
  };
}
else {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return classReg( c ).test( elem.className );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    if ( !hasClass( elem, c ) ) {
      elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
    }
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.className = elem.className.replace( classReg( c ), ' ' );
  };
}

function toggleClass( elem, c ) {
  var fn = hasClass( elem, c ) ? removeClass : addClass;
  fn( elem, c );
}

var classie = {
  // full names
  hasClass: hasClass,
  addClass: addClass,
  removeClass: removeClass,
  toggleClass: toggleClass,
  // short names
  has: hasClass,
  add: addClass,
  remove: removeClass,
  toggle: toggleClass
};

// transport
if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
  // AMD
  define( classie );
} else {
  // browser global
  window.classie = classie;
}

})( window );
```

```css
.menu_item {
  display: block;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
.menu_link {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.05em;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
.menu_list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.menu {
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0 ;
}
.menu-miranda .menu_item {
  margin: 10px 5px;
  position: relative;
}
.menu-miranda .menu_link {
  color: #b5b5b5;
  display: block;
  min-width: auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  transition: color 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.menu-miranda .menu_link:hover, .menu-miranda .menu_link:focus {
    color: #929292;
}
.menu-miranda .menu_item-current .menu_link {
    color: #d94f5c;
}
.menu-miranda .menu_item::before, .menu-miranda .menu_item::after, .menu-miranda .menu_link::before, .menu-miranda .menu_link::after {
    background: #d94f5c none repeat scroll 0 0;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    transition: transform 0.1s cubic-bezier(1, 0.68, 0.16, 0.9) 0s;
}
.menu-miranda .menu_item::before, .menu-miranda .menu_item::after {
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    transform: scale3d(1, 0, 1);
    width: 2px;
}
.menu-miranda .menu_item::before {
    left: 0;
    transform-origin: 50% 100% 0;
}
.menu-miranda .menu_item::after {
    right: 0;
    transform-origin: 50% 0 0;
}
.menu-miranda .menu_link::before, .menu-miranda .menu_link::after {
    height: 2px;
    left: 0;
    transform: scale3d(0, 1, 1);
    width: 100%;
}
.menu-miranda .menu_link::before {
    top: 0;
    transform-origin: 0 50% 0;
}
.menu-miranda .menu_link::after {
    bottom: 0;
    transform-origin: 100% 50% 0;
}
.menu-miranda .menu_item .menu_link::after {
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.menu-miranda .menu_item-current .menu_link::after {
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
.menu-miranda .menu_item::before {
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.menu-miranda .menu_item-current::before {
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.menu-miranda .menu_item .menu_link::before {
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.menu-miranda .menu_item-current .menu_link::before {
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.menu-miranda .menu_item-current::after {
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.menu-miranda .menu_item-current::before, .menu-miranda .menu_item-current::after, .menu-miranda .menu_item-current .menu_link::before, .menu-miranda .menu_item-current .menu_link::after {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-collapse collapse pull-right menu menu-miranda">
                        <ul class="menu_list" id="top-navigation">
                            <li class="menu_item menu_item-current"><a class="menu_link"  href="#home">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="menu_item"><a class="menu_link" href="#service">Services</a></li>
                            <li class="menu_item"><a class="menu_link"  href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                            <li class="menu_item"><a class="menu_link"  href="#about">About</a></li>
                            <li class="menu_item"><a class="menu_link"  href="#clients">Clients</a></li>
                            <li class="menu_item"><a class="menu_link"  href="#price">Price</a></li>
                            <li class="menu_item"><a class="menu_link"  href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

This is my code its work on click event but I want to set it in mouse hover, how can I do that ?

Comment: Hard to test without your full code. Please post full code. Otherwise -https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Comment: @WillDiFruscio The question is edited please check now. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Akash Agrawal, but you need to add a hover out (mouse out) state as well to the hover function in jQuery - otherwise all elements you mouse over will get the calss added to them but never removed.. I tested it using your code and it was giving the horizontal lines on the hover - but not the verticals. Could be the selector i used, but at least it gives you a hover based effect you can investigate further.

```
$(".menu_link" ).hover(function(){$(this).addClass("menu_item-current")},
       function(){$(this).removeClass("menu_item-current")
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like :

```
$( ".class/#div" ).hover(function() {
  $( this ).addClass("menu_item-current");
});
```

I hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```js
$(function(){
 $('.menu_link').on('mouseenter', function(){
  $(this).closest('.menu_item').addClass('menu_item-current');
 }); 
 $('.menu_link').on('mouseleave', function(){
  $(this).closest('.menu_item').removeClass('menu_item-current');
 }); 
});
```